# i cannot log in given that i have encrypted my password in the database

Tags: c#, sql, encryption, passwords

here is my registration page with the encryption method. i encrypted the password:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(scm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (temp == 1) // check if user already exist.
            {
                Response.Write("User already existing");
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    protected void btn_Registration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string insertQuery = "insert into UserData(Username,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Password,CustomerType,DeliveryAddress,Zip,ContactNumber)values(@Username,@Firstname,@Lastname,@Email,@Password,@CustomerType,@DeliveryAddress,@Zip,@ContactNumber)";
            SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUser.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtFN.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtLN.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Encrypt(txtPW.Text));
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerType", RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryAddress", txtAddress.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", txtZip.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", txtContact.Text);

            scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Session["Contact"]= txtContact.Text;
            Session["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
            Session["DeliveryAddress"] = txtAddress.Text;
            label_register_success.Text = ("Registration Successful!");
            //Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    private string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
```

and here is my login code with the decryption method. i decrypted the password before checking if it matches the the password input by the user:

```
 protected void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(scm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkPassword = "select Password from UserData where Username ='" + txtUser.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
            string password = passCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            password = Decrypt(password);
            if (password == txtPassword.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = txtUser.Text;
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Logged In')</script>");
                Response.Redirect("OrderNow.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblcrederror.Text = ("Credentials dont match");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            lblcrederror.Text = ("Credentials dont match");
        }
    }
    private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
```

what am i missing here? please help. i tried to input a working login but it gives me an error (Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.) my password is on nvarchar(MAX) in database.

Comment: the first code image sir. thats the encryption method @user1666620

Comment: Shouldn't this line - `if (password == txtPassword.Text)` be encrypting the password text box to see if it matches the saved value which has already been encrypted? e.g. `if (password == Encrypt(txtPassword.Text))`

Comment: please see the edited query. i have edditted the log in codes. @GarethD

Answer (score 0):

Your login function needs to pull the user's password from the database, and decrypt it with that key. If the decrypted password matches the entered password let them in.

I would use salted hashing though, unless you have a specific reason to be able to view the user's passwords. Then you would just need to compare hashes to login.

Once you get that password from the database, pass it to this.

```
private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
    encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
    encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
            cs.Close();
        }
        cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
 }
 return cipherText;
}
```

then if cipherText = User's entered password, log them in.

Comment: do you have an example sir? would really appreciate it

Comment: a example decryption or a same of salted hashing?

Comment: hmm both? whatever to make my code work. hehe thanks sir

Comment: so ill just add this up along with the encrytion method?

Comment: can you thoroughly guide me sir since im new? please please :)

Comment: add this : password=decrypt(password);   

right above your if statement in your login function. then it should work if you added the decrypt function to your code.

Comment: i added the decrypt method in my log in codes. also, i have added password=decrypt(password); above the  if (password == txtPassword.Text). i tried to register but failed to login :(

Comment: debug and go line by line and hover over both passwords when it gets past the if statement to see what it's pulling back for the passwords.

Comment: see my eddited query. is it the right codes and the right place they should be?

Comment: Looks good. Not sure why you are removing spaces , you could probably remove .Replace(" ", "")

Comment: okay. i tried to log in with a not encrypted password. it wont let me as well. and has an error.  Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

Comment: It should work, I've tested the encryption and decryption functions. It has to be with how you are storing or retrieving them in sql. Make sure your Password field in sql is big enough to fit the encryption string

Comment: its in nvarchar(MAX), please see the editted codes. its the whole code for the login and register. would really really appreciate it sir

Comment: Try what @GarethD said. Instead of decrypting the password. Just use this. I think it will work with this encryption method since your using the same key everytime. Take out the decrypt part above the if statement and use this in the if statement

if (password == Encrypt(txtPassword.Text))

Comment: so will i add the encrypt method as well in the login code? because it only has the decryption method in it. the encryption method is in the registration code.  thank you and please

Comment: Yes. Take out decryption code. Just use what I posted in last comment

Comment: tried it. removed the decryption code out of the login and replaced it with the encryption mode. tried to register(password encrypted) but not able to log in :(